# android how to create a service that make a notification in real time (like facebook or whatapps)

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I'm trying to create a background service that every "X" minutes consult a webservice and if response "ok" generate a Notification on the notification Bar

I'm not sure if is a android service o Broadcast receiver the thing that I need

Thank anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, don't pull a page from web-service every X minutes -- this drains battery a lot, use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) (former C2DM -- Cloud To Device Messaging) instead to get your information updates -- it's very lightweight and very efficient and shares one existing data connection for all applications.

Comment: thank for the suggested but the central problem is the background service that create the notification, I don't know how to do it

Comment: you may get a hold of `NotificationManager` and use it to create notification, see the answer below

Answer (score 1):

[NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: I known that, but what thing generate that nofication?, I suppose that need a Handler that create the notification and I don't not how it do

Comment: You should really read the Android documentation. See docs for Service here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html. But as lenik mentioned, Cloud To Device Messaging would definitely be the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a broadcast receiver (inside its own class, plus a bit of code in the manifest) that reacts to the USER_PRESENT action (when user unlocks screen) or the BOOT_COMPLETED (when cellphone finishes loading the OS and all other stuff). Boot activates the Broadcast, the broadcast starts the service. Inside the onStartCommand() method of your service, you run your connection to the webservice every X minutes. Your service should Implement AsyncTask to connect to the Web service. In the onCompleted() method of that task, you call the notifications.

MANIFEST:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<receiver android:name="classes.myReceiver" >        
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <service  android:name="classes.myService">        
        </service>
```

CLASS:

```
public class myReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {     
        Intent service = new Intent(ctx, myService.class);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)||intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)||intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            ctx.startService(service);
            }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            ctx.stopService(service);  
            }
        }
}
```

SAMPLE NOTIFICATION

```
    private void showNotification() {               
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setContent(getNotificationContent());
        notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);

            notificationBuilder.setTicker("Hello");
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif_icon);

        mNotificationManager.notify(R.id.notification_layout, notificationBuilder.build()); 
        }

 private RemoteViews getNotificationContent() {  

            RemoteViews notificationContent = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.keyphrase_recogniser_notification);
        notificationContent.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, "title");
            notificationContent.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_subtitle, "subtitle");
return notificationContent;
            }
```

This is a broad guide, if you need more specific code let us know.